# How do I make an array in JS hold data? json and can run it.?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, fetch

I would like to know if there is a way that we can use the array freely. ,Now I need to give console.log(ArtistMusic[0]) goes into the scope of data.forEach So the data can be retrieved and used.

```
 let ArtistMusic = [];

  fetch('url')
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        let newArtist = {
          artist_id: item.artist_id,
          artist_name: item.artist_name,
          image_filename: item.image_filename
        };
        ArtistMusic.push(newArtist);
      });
    console.log(ArtistMusic[0]); <-------this
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
```

I just want to know if there is another way. Or is there any way that it can be called outside of this scope, like this?

```
 let ArtistMusic = [];

  fetch('url')
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
        let newArtist = {
          artist_id: item.artist_id,
          artist_name: item.artist_name,
          image_filename: item.image_filename
        };
        ArtistMusic.push(newArtist);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
    console.log(ArtistMusic[0]); <---------------------this show undefined on console
```